# Deciphering Coding Shortcuts

Tags: pure-function

I'm having trouble deciphering why the following couple of expressions evaluate the way they do.

```
#&@@
```

This returns the first value of a list. Why? Naïvely I would have expected this to replace the head of the list with the list itself.

```
1 ## &@@
```

This multiplies a list together, like

```
Times@@
```

Why is that? I imagine it's for the same reason as the first shortcut.

Comment: Take a look there and at linked ref pages: [What the @#%^&*?!](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/5478)

Comment: It does not strictly "return the first value of a list": it just returns the first argument to the function following `@@`, for lists, the full form is `List[x,y,z]`, and the 1st argument is x, which is also the first value of a list. Try `# & @@ func[c, b, a]`

Comment: You can also try to translate short-form expressions by wrapping them in `FullForm[Hold[...]]`. That displays the long form from which you can go to the help pages more easily.

Answer (score 3):

```
#&@@list === First@list
```

because `#===#1`(first argument), try `#2&@@{7,6,5,4}`

In the second case `1 x` means `Times[1,x]` so the expression

```
1 ## &@@{5,4,3,2} === Times[1,Sequence[5,4,3,2]] == Times[1,5,4,3,1]
```